# Applying user defined functions to a specific column of each dataframe in a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, user-defined-functions

**Background**

Hi everyone! I am currently conducting a project which requires me to estimate within-study variance through bootstrapping of model residuals, and then calculating the SEE for each sample. This process has to be done on a model-by-model basis.

I have started off by creating a list of dataframes, which are split based on the factor variable `model` using the following code `list.meta<- split(new.meta, new.meta$model)` where each dataframe contains the data pertaining to a single model. I have supplied a reproducible example below and have limited this to 3 models; however my full dataset contains 13. From there I have two user defined functions: One for calculating the SEE, and another which generates 1000 bootstrapped samples, calculating the SEE for each using the previously defined SEE function. I have supplied both below as well for transparency.

**User defined functions**

```
#Define SEE function 
SEE<- function(x){
  sqrt((sum(x)/(length(x)-2))^2)
}

#Define function for generating bootstrap samples and calculating SEE for each sample

Bootstrap<- function(x){
  int<- lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(x, replace = T))
  Calc.SEE<- sapply(int, SEE)
}
```

Where *x* is the `Residuals` column  from a given dataframe 'i'

**Data**

```
list(`1` = structure(list(Study = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Model = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Residuals = c(26.96774194, 24.35483871, 15.74193548, 15.70967742, 
13.22580645, 12.87096774, 11.77419355, 10.67741935, 10.58064516, 
8.548387097, 8, 5.548387097, 5.35483871, 5.322580645, 2.612903226, 
1.483870968, 1.225806452, 0.258064516)), row.names = c(NA, 18L
), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(Study = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Model = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Residuals = c(20.19354839, 16.5483871, 15.74193548, 
14.61290323, 7.064516129, 6.580645161, 5.64516129, 4.580645161, 
4.612903226, 3.612903226, 3.35483871, 2.741935484, 2.419354839, 
1.64516129, 1.35483871, 1.903225806, 0.516129032)), row.names = 19:35, class = "data.frame"), 
    `3` = structure(list(Study = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Model = c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
    ), Residuals = c(23.80645161, 17.41935484, 15.58064516, 13.22580645, 
    11.32258065, 10.4516129, 6.709677419, 6.193548387, 5.741935484, 
    4.870967742, 4.322580645, 2.709677419, 2.677419355, 1.032258065, 
    1.129032258, 0.451612903, 1.064516129)), row.names = 36:52, class = "data.frame"))
```

**problem/question**

So, here's my problem: I need to apply the bootstrap function to the `residuals` column of each model, with the output eventually being a list of length 13 (where each element of the list is a vector comprised of 1000 SEE values) or as a dataframe/matrix with 13 columns and 1000 rows (the second is preferable as it will be used for further analyses and the package takes as input a dataframe).

I imagine one of the best ways to do this would be either through a `for` loop or though one of functions from the `apply` family. However, as far as syntax goes, I have no idea how to actually apply the function to a specific column of each dataframe when these are nested in a list format

**What I have tried**

1. Attempt one was to use the `lapply` function.

```
dat<- lapply(na.omit(new.data[[i]][, 4]), Bootstrap)
```

The `[[i]][, 4]` is my attempt at telling R to use the data from the fourth column from the ith element of the list. This partially worked but returned a list of length 18? Some of list elements also made no sense.

2. The second option i'm working on is to use a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:seq_along(new.data)){
result<- Bootstrap(new.data[[i]][,4])
return(result)
}
```

but this returns an error

```
In 1:seq_along(new.data) :
  numerical expression has 13 elements: only the first used
```

I also have no idea how to actually save the results into list or matrix format and my `for` loop skills could use more work... so there's that.

There's probably going to a very simple answer to this, so thank you in advance for any and all suggestions. I really need to up my hours practicing coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
dat <- lapply(new.data, function(dataFrameInList) {
    Bootstrap(na.omit(dataFrameInList[["Residuals"]]))
})
```

I hope the naming is clear to understand. When using `lapply` over a list, it grabs each element, in your case the `data.frames`I called `dataFrameInList` as the "loop variable". Then, choose the residuals via `dataFrameInList[["Residuals"]]`. Alternatively you could use `dataFrameInList[,"Residuals"]` or `dataFrameInList[,4]`. Throw away the `NA`s and finally apply your `Bootstrap`-function.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! I decided to change ```lapply``` to ```sapply``` as well to get the data in matrix format. Your explanation and naming was very clear, but there is just a couple of things I don't get: 

1. Why does this work but indexing with ```[[i]][, 4]``` does not? I get that it iterates over each element which is a ```data.frame```

2. I get that the function is a so-called "anonymous" function, but how does it work? Could you explain a little more as I think this will help my thought process for future problems. Again, thank you greatly.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family does help you

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help, Jonas. I have now been able to streamline the process into one single chunk of code using ```tapply``` and anonymous functions at each stage of the process.